# I get an error doing a CountDown

Tags: android, countdown

i am Newbie and i am receiving errors and i don´t know why D:

When i press Button my app crashes.
Here my code:

I tried different versions of countdowns and no one runs D:
Thanks...

**MainActivity**

```
    package com.example.chrontest;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Jungle CuentaAtras = new Jungle(6000, 1000);
            CuentaAtras.start();
        }});


    }
}
```

**Jungle.class**

```
    package com.example.chrontest;

    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Jungle extends CountDownTimer{

    TextView Texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    public Jungle(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private TextView findViewById(int textview1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Texto.setText("GAME OVER");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Texto.setText ("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

    }
 }
```

**And here my LogCat:**

```
12-03 04:13:41.175: D/gralloc_goldfish(1395): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-03 04:13:52.325: D/AndroidRuntime(1395): Shutting down VM
12-03 04:13:52.325: W/dalvikvm(1395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.example.chrontest.Jungle.onTick(Jungle.java:28)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-03 04:13:52.345: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 04:13:53.925: I/Process(1395): Sending signal. PID: 1395 SIG: 9
```

**UPDATED:**

Lol i don´t put my layout, and.. today i see that i don´t have a view or anything to see my countdown, or just this will appear in the screen, lol i don´t know :|

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jungle` class is not an `activity class`. So you cannot get the

`TextView Texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` here and use it

What you should do is calculate the `countdown` and give a callback to  your `activity` class. There you should set the `TextView`

**UPDATE**

```
package com.example.chrontest;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Jungle extends CountDownTimer{

Context mContext;

public Jungle(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, Context context) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
mContext = context;
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mcontext.MethodToSetText("YourText");
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mcontext.MethodToSetText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

}

}
```

And call

`Jungle CuentaAtras = new Jungle(6000, 1000, this);`

Comment: Yes, tomorrow i did it, because the guy of tutorial did it.. But i get an error in Public Class Jungle (this says me that i need to remove invalid modifiers) and if i click it, its delete "public" this is why i created a new class XD
Your question is excellent, but i can´t do the fu***** timer yet. D:

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @Arju is perfect for problem you are facing however i want to add that you don't need a separate class just for updating timer. You can achieve that using the code below, just add this in your `onClickListener` and change `mTextField` with you `textView` name.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

This counter will start at 30 sec (30000 milliseconds) and stop at 1 sec (1000 milli sec).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the code, i tried tomorrow but i can´t. I get errors :|
And i am really newbie o.O
And.. what is mTextField ? to what its refer ?

Comment: `mTextField` is textView which should be replaced by `Texto`. Just change all the`mTextField` with `Texto` and then you won't find any errors.

Comment: Lol, i said it in the first answer. Ok , thanks! :D
I can run it :P

Comment: @FabianMontossi I am glad that i could help you and a FYI whenever you see a answer that solves your problem in one way or another then please upvote it. Thanks.. !! Happy Coding...

Comment: I forget to do it, sorry xD
But i cant vote up yet because i dont have 15 points, i put "Correct answer", or tick :D
Thanks again :D